# How to set custom effect for android camera

Tags: android, filter

I want to build a camera app like Thermal Camera. I try to use color filter to set effect for preview camera. But I only find a solution like

```
cameraParams.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_POSTERIZE);
```

How do I customize effect for android camera?